# Python - Trying to Get My Sound File To Play On Startup of Application

Tags: python, audio, user-interface, wav, pythoncard

I have used the following code and I am not sure why it is not working.

```
from PythonCard import model

playSound = 1

class MainWindow(model.Background):
    pass

app = model.Application(MainWindow)
app.MainLoop()

if playSound == 1:
    s = Sound()
    s.read('start.wav')
    s.play
    playSound = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesis to call a function:

```
s.play()
```

Comment: Should I keep my playSound variable with this?